# Receive touch events of parent and child simultaneously (multi-touch on UI)

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I've created an Android game consisting of a RelativeLayout and a Button. Players should touch somewhere on the RelativeLayout first and then touch the button without releasing the touch on the RelativeLayout.

It seems that the Button doesn't receive any touch anymore as long as the players finger is still on the RelativeLayout.

Is there any solution for the Button to get the touch event? I've read the article about "Prevent Touch Event Theft in Android" (https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/prevent-touch-event-theft-in-android/) but this doesn't work for me.

Thank you!

EDIT: Added code example. "Button touched" and "RelativeLayout touched" are both printed when touched individually (with release of the first touch). When I touch the RelativeLayout first and then the button without releasing RelativeLayout, only the message for the RelativeLayout is printed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Button clicked");
                return false;
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "RelativeLayout clicked");
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Post you relevant code so we can see what's happening. Odds are you've consumed the touch event in your RelativeLayout, you clearly want to use it in the Layout but pass it down to the Button as well.

Comment: Hi Sam, I added a code example above. When I touch RelativeLayout first and then the button (without releasing the touch on the RelativeLayout), the touch on the button is not registered.

Comment: Same issue here, if the parent of a button is touched the second touch on the button is not working for some reason. Though I can multi touch several buttons. just not the container first and then a button.